# What's the matrix representation of this 3-qubit CZ circuit?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

How do I calculate the matrix representation of this part of a teleportation circuit? It must be a matrix of dimension 8.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Nillmer. Welcome to [quantumcomputing.se]! I recommend trying to figure it by yourself. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Controlled_(cX_cY_cZ)_gates). It looks like a simple controlled-$Z$ gate to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to build a sort of quantum IF statement. 
You have in quantum computing projector operators telling you whether a qubit is 0 or 1:
$$ P_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ P_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix} $$

Then we have the Z gate :

$$ Z= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1  
\end{pmatrix} $$

To build the unitary for your controlled operation, we do :
$$ CZ = P_0 \otimes I \otimes I + P_1 \otimes I \otimes Z $$

with $ \otimes $ the tensor product.
That means, if your first qubit is in the $ |0\rangle $ state, we apply the identity operation, otherwise we apply the Z operator only on the third qubit.

Comment: Just a side note: $P_0 = |0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $P_1 = |1\rangle\langle 1|$.